# R- how to fill matrix with for loop

Tags: r, matrix, confidence-interval

I'm trying to create a matrix using a for loop, simple but not working so far .... I'm starting now with R.

n = 17

M is a matrix containing kendall tau-b values, ncol = 10 nrows = 1.

```
n <- length(plot[,2]);
z1a <- 1.96;

M1=matrix(data=NA, ncol= 10, nrow = 2);

for (i in M[,1:10]){
  #print(i)
  zr <- (1/2)*log((1+i)/(1-i));
  SE <- sqrt(0.437/(n-4));
  zU <- zr+z1a*SE;
  zL <- zr-z1a*SE;
  rL <- (exp(2*zL)-1)/(exp(2*zL)+1);
  rU <- (exp(2*zU)-1)/(exp(2*zU)+1);

  #print(rL)
  #print(rU)

  M1 [1,1:10] <- (exp(2*zL)-1)/(exp(2*zL)+1);
  M1 [2,1:10] <- (exp(2*zU)-1)/(exp(2*zU)+1);
}
```

The last line of code is just to understand how I want to fill matrix. How can i solve the issue?

Comment: There are some missing aspects in your question that would make it easier for us to understand your issue. For instance, n is unknown, M is unknown. Also, by your code, the first and second rows of the matrix M1 would have recurring values.

Comment: Make a `list` first, then convert to `matrix`. For instance, try `L <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)` then `matrix(L,ncol=3)` to see how this might work.

Comment: I corrected the question...

Comment: The problem is that matrix always fills with the same values.

Comment: Do you mean `for(i in 1:10)`? I think you're confused about the indices that you're trying to use. Make sure you've assigned the correct index to `i` and that it's accessing the value you expect out of your matrix and calculations.

Comment: Yes I do. But if i print rU and rL, everything is alright.

Comment: Hahah it'is true. I'm very confused, i am learning from self-taught with many difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. Is this what you are looking for? I have initiated M as a random uniform number from 0 to 1

```
z1a <- 1.96;
n <- 17
set.seed(1)

M = runif(10)
M1 = matrix(data = NA, ncol = 10, nrow = 2);

zr <- (1/2)*log((1+M)/(1-M));
SE <- sqrt(0.437/(n-4));
zU <- zr+z1a*SE;
zL <- zr-z1a*SE;
rL <- (exp(2*zL)-1)/(exp(2*zL)+1);
rU <- (exp(2*zU)-1)/(exp(2*zU)+1);

M1 [1,1:10] <- (exp(2*zL)-1)/(exp(2*zL)+1);    
M1 [2,1:10] <- (exp(2*zU)-1)/(exp(2*zU)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written the above answer in a simple way.

```
# Create a matrix of 3X5 
M1 = matrix(data = NA, ncol = 5, nrow = 3);

row1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
row2<-c(6,7,8,9,10)
M1[1,1:5]<-row1
M1[2,1:5]<-row2

M1
```

Output:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```